# How do I get source code from Google code?

Tags: svn, google-code

How can I get editable source code off of Google Code?

(I'm looking into SipDroid and Siphon in particular.)

**EDIT:**

I'm not looking to check back in, I just want the source so I can use it in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want editable code, you should join the project.

If you want to pull down the source and then make it editable (you won't be able to check things back in), go to the following URL and follow the instructions for using svn:

http://code.google.com/p/siphon/source/checkout

Comment: @Moshe - Follow the directions from the People page: How-to: Join this project by contacting the project owners, usually through participating in a mailing list.

Comment: There is only one person and it doesn't seem like anyone can join.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the [project page](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/)
2. Click on "[Source](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/checkout)"
3. Type the command that is given to you:

   ```
   $ svn checkout http://sipdroid.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ sipdroid-read-only
   ```

Answer (score 1):

SipDroid: http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/checkout

Siphon: http://code.google.com/p/siphon/source/checkout

Answer (score 1):

Point of order:  The word "checkout" may be confusing you.  In the context of SVN, it just means "get stuff out", not "lock this for my exclusive use" as it would in the context of, say, a public book library.  I say this because you mention "getting" the code without "checking it back in".